# Could this code break wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
//on some hosts the uploads directory is not automatically created 
//on WP auto install so we create it

if (!is_dir(ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads')) {
    mkdir(ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads');
}
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue in which some people who install my WP theme get an error (no description) or a blank white screen. I'm thinking that perhaps the code above could be the culprit on certain setups, perhaps depending on support for mkdir?

Comment: Is this in your theme? This looks like something that is in the WordPress core.

Comment: @Dominic good point. Why is a theme creating the uploads dir in the first place?

Comment: Yes its a theme directive to override the WP default settings. I've encountered some situations where the uploads directory is not present on new WP installs. My theme expects this directory as I store header images there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `wp-content` is not writable. That should result in a warning at most, though, not a fatal error.

`mkdir` could also be disabled by the provider in a safe mode context, but that should be extremely rare.

There's only one way to find out really: Have people activate `error_reporting()` and see what the blog spits out.

If I were to shoot in the dark, I would first check whether you use any PHP 5 specific keywords (`private` `public`.....) and clients still use PHP4.